# Modify beginning of PATH-variable with os.environ in python

Tags: python, path, environment-variables

I know that I can get and modify the `PATH` variable by doing something like 
`os.environ["PATH"] += "path/to/dir".`

But is there any way to ensure that the new path gets written to the beginning of `PATH`?

Comment: yes you can do it the same way you would manipulate strings however, why would you ever do this in Python? this screams of bad practice

Comment: Yes. Just add the path this way:
`os.environ['PATH'] = "path/to/dir" + os.environ['PATH']`

Comment: I'm trying to set  a directory containing a symlink to a conda-python-interpreter on the PATH-variable at runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.environ["PATH"] = "path/to/dir" + os.pathsep + os.getenv("PATH")`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

`os.pathsep`

The character conventionally used by the operating system to separate search path components (as in PATH), such as ':' for POSIX or ';' for Windows. Also available via os.path.

`os.getenv(key, default=None)`

Return the value of the environment variable key if it exists, or default if it doesn’t. key, default and the result are str.

Comment: add some explanation for what each os calls does.